# Error when trying to create new Gauge project

Tags: visual-studio-code, getgauge

I gonna start to work with Gauge, but I'm getting this error when I try to create a new Gauge project with VS Code:

> PS C:\Users\matheus.nogueira\Teste_Gauge> Gauge: Create new Gauge Project
>   Gauge: : The term 'Gauge:' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Gauge: Create new Gauge Project
>   + ~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Gauge::String) [],CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I followed the guide from Gauge's site and Gauge's extension on VS Code, but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know how to create the project properly?

Comment: Is the error exclusive to Visual Studio Code? Project creation works fine from a regular PowerShell window?

Comment: No, I can't create from PowerShell too. But I can execute 'gauge run specs' from both VS Code and PowerShell.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library so sorry if it's a dumb question but... Are you literally getting `Gauge: Create new Gauge Project` injected into a PS prompt when you execute the `Gauge: Create new Gauge Project` command in command palette? Are you sure you aren't typing in the wrong pane?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it because the Gauge extension page says: "Execute the Command 'Gauge: Create new Gauge Project' and select the appropriate template to create a new Gauge Project". I've never worked with VS Code, maybe I didn't understand the correct way to create the project.

Comment: There's [a picture](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/getgauge/gauge-vscode/master/images/newProj.jpg). You run commands from *View/ Command Palette*.

Comment: Omg, Thank you ! I was trying at terminal, I even didn't know about this command palette.